# Is mkdir -p safe to parallelize?

Tags: filesystems, multithreading, mkdir

I'm writing Makefile rules like this:

```
out/%.x: ...
    mkdir -p $(@D)/
    ...
```

I intend to parallelize this Makefile (`-j`), which will trigger many `mkdir -p`'s to simultaneously.

Is this safe? Or do I need to guard against problems by ensuring `mkdir -p` only happens once?

(**Note** that `mkdir -p` isn't necessarily a single operation at the file system level, unlike `mkdir`.)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/152823/is-it-dangerous-to-have-several-parallel-jobs-create-the-same-directory-at-the-s https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569290/running-mkdir-p-in-parallel-under-mac-os-x-quits-before-directory-is-created

Comment: @muru: Thanks for the links, but the serverfault answers say *"This should not be a problem if this is properly handled (i.e. good error handling)"* and *"I guess it comes down to what mkdir -p does"* which is... kinda useless when the entire question is about what `mkdir -p` does? And the second one also seems to suggest the problem in that question might be something else for that OP.

Answer (score 4):

The rationale for [POSIX `mkdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html) says

> Because no error is produced if any path component already exists, the **-p** option is also useful to ensure that a particular directory exists.

This suggests that parallel use should be safe. I can understand your doubts, given the potential for races, so let’s look at an implementation...

In GNU `coreutils`, the `-p` option ends up being handled by [`mkancesdirs`](https://sources.debian.org/src/coreutils/8.30-3/lib/mkancesdirs.c/), which has a helpful description which should allay your fears:

> Ensure that the ancestor directories of FILE exist, using an
>      algorithm that should work even if two processes execute this
>      function in parallel.

(Instead of immediately acting on errors from `mkdir`, it tries to `chdir` into each component directory and only fails if that fails.)

If you’re using GNU Make, you could use its [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) to handle directories in the same way as other prerequisites:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%/:
        mkdir -p $@

out/%.x: $$(@D)/ ...
        ...
```